# How to split a long lines hex string?

Tags: windows, hexadecimal, hex-editor, hexdump

I've a long hex string like this 100000006465780A3033350025979BA5B30D4516F6.

Is there an easy way I can split these with a space per hex coded byte so I get 10000000 64 65 78 A3 03 33 35 00 25 97 9B A5 B3 0D 45 16 and remove the last two words F6?

I have multiple lines. I want to manage these lines.

Is there an easy way I can split these lines at a single time  (or another easily accessible tool) I can use under Windows?

Comment: As you do want a view that a hex editor would offer what's the source of that data? Why not use a hex editor in the first place? You could probably use a regular expression with a replace.

Comment: Welcome Mona.  Are all the lines the same length and conform to the same format?  If so, you can write a regex (regular expression) to do this.  You can then use the regex in a text editor that supports regex to perform the changes.

Comment: To remove the F6 it would be along the lines of looking for `F6$` and for the splitting you could do something akin to `(..)` and replace it with `$1 `.

Comment: I used 010 editors for using files in hex format but I want that format above in questions.

Comment: 010 editor does not give me hex format files with offset values and hex values with spaces.

Comment: Mona, are you using Windows, Linux, MacOSX or something else?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take our short [tour] to learn how the site is supposed to work. Important information (e.g. the OS) should be in the question, not in comments. You can [edit] the question.